# Is there a iPhone 3 specific media query?

Tags: ios, iphone, background, safari, media-queries

`background-size:cover` does not seem to work on iPhone 3. I've read somewhere that using `background-size:100%;` instead should solve the problem, and it does. However, it makes the background on Iphone 4 look ugly.

I've searched on the internet but all I find are queries for both the Iphone 3 and 4. Is there a media query for JUST the iPhone 3?

**EDIT: I posted my solution in the answer below**

Comment: iPhone 3? do you mean iPhone 3G/3Gs or iOS 3?

Comment: I meant 3G/3GS, but I fixed the problem, found a blog post which listed media queries for different iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.

**[This blog post](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/02/24/responsive-mobile-design-media-queries-css3-ios-2/)** has a list of media queries for specific iPhone versions.

```
<!-- iPhone 2G, 3G, 3GS Portrait -->
@media only screen and (device-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait) and not (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* CSS3 Rules for iPhone in Portrait Orientation */
}

<!-- iPhone 2G, 3G, 3GS Landscape -->
@media only screen and (device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) and not (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* CSS3 Rules for iPhone in Landscape Orientation */
}
```

As you can see it only targets up to 3GS.